# js/jquery focus textarea не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно вызвать событие `focus()` для элемента `textarea`, средствами кода? Чтобы произошло тоже самое, как когда нажимаешь на поле `textarea` мышкой.
То есть выделение (стиля textarea:focus), ну и при нажатии клавиш, текст вводится в поле.

Пробовал `.focus()`, `.select()`, и другие методы, но они не работают.

Comment: Код покажи, людям гадать, что да как ты пытался?

Comment: @Air прочитай полностью вопрос

Comment: Понятно, что кодом... А при каком событии этот код должен сработать? При каких обстоятельствах?  Опиши вопрос нормально...

Comment: @Air $(textarea).focus() то работает, но дело в том что при фокусе упомянутой функцией, у текстареии не работает стиль, textarea:focus { // }, но при ручном фокусе, стили применяются.

Comment: @Vlad я вам уже оставил сообщение ниже. Фокус текстарии выполняется,обрабатывается событие focus. Принимайте ответ или излагайте свои мысли правильно. Можете перезапустить, для вас тригер был добавлен специально чтоб инициализировать события без пользователя.

Comment: ТС не упомянул, что не работает у него, скорее всего, в Firefox. Баг известный, в инете "костылей" достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('textarea').focus(function(e){ alert('Работает же')})
$('textarea').trigger('focus')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="100" row="100"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Введите в консоли браузера $('.snippet-code textarea').focus()  , алерта не будет. А я как раз таки пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы выполнить фокус текстареи кодом, а не кликом вручную.

Comment: @Vlad может потому-что его там нет?)))) Выполните код выше как пример, всё отрабатывает...)

Answer (score 1):

Это не ответ, это вопрос))))  Объясни мне, что у тя может тут не работать?????

```css
textarea{
background:red;
}
textarea:focus{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="100" row="100"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').trigger('focus');
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on("focus","textarea", function(){
        console.log("textarea focus");
     
    });
  $('textarea').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>con</textarea>
```

Comment: Странно, в консоли логируеться, а outline (синяя рамка) при фокусе кодом, не появляется

Comment: @Vlad Что не появляется ? синяя рамка ? почему не появляется ))) я её вижу сейчас, смени/обнови/удали  браузер